# Why the AJAX function is only executed in the end?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I've this code below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
                url: "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Negocio/OfertaParticulares/_api/web/folders('Dinamico')/folders?$select=ID,Title,Created,Name",
                type: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                },        

                success: onQuerySucceeded,
                error: onQueryFailed
            });


        });

        function onQuerySucceeded(data) 
        {

            var dataresult = data.d.results;
            dataresult = [].slice.call(dataresult);
            dataresult.forEach(function(key, value){
                if(key.Name != "Forms")
                {

                    jQuery("#SubFolders").append("<br/>Folder Name: "+ key.Name+"<br/>");

                    jQuery("#SubFolders").append("Folder Name TEST SubFolders<br/>");

                    callSubFolder();

                }
            });
        }

        function onQueryFailed() 
        {
            alert('Sorry An Error Has Occurred!');
        }


        function callSubFolder(){
            jQuery("#SubFolders").append("Folder Name TEST callSubFolder<br/>");

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Negocio/OfertaParticulares/_api/web/folders('Dinamico')/folders?$select=ID,Title,Created,Name",
                type: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                },        

                success: function(data) {  
                   jQuery("#SubFolders").append("Folder Name TEST callSubFolder successfunction<br/>");
                },  
                error: function(error) {  
                    console.log("ERRO POST");
                } 
            });

        }
<div id="SubFolders">
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

I want this result:

[image]

Why the *Folder Name TEST callSubFolder successfunction* is only executed in the end? What can I do to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `async: false` for your callSubFolder function.

```
function callSubFolder(){
            jQuery("#SubFolders").append("Folder Name TEST callSubFolder<br/>");

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/folders('MyDoc4')/folders?$select=ID,Title,Created,Name",
                type: "GET",
                async: false,
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    jQuery("#SubFolders").append("Folder Name TEST callSubFolder successfunction<br/>");
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log("ERRO POST");
                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Async false!.... that is a really bad bad idea and not a good practice at all).

You should implement promises, refer to this:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-2013-implement-deferred-and-promise-object-in-javascript-asynchronous/